# modify Android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, qemu

Is there a way to modify the Android emulator? For example, can we somehow intercept user inputs to the emulator and interpret them differently? Also, is there existing tools to do dynamic binary rewrite inside the emulator or qemu?

Comment: It's all open source, so of course you can modify it.  But you are going to have to decide if you want to modify the emulator itself, or modify the build of android running inside of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The emulator is emulating the hardware. You can do dynamic binary rewrites inside the emulator in exactly the same as on a device (for example, using LD_PRELOAD for native, or by changing the loader), or not at all. There is nothing that the fact it is an emulator helps you with, as there are too many layers between the emulator (hardware) and the abstraction you are trying to change. In the middle, you have the kernel, binary loader, dalvik virtual machine etc.

User input might be easier, but, again, it seems to me it will be easier to change the open source framework code that processes the input, rather than the emulator itself.

Shachar